# Is the field $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/3},3^{1/4})$ a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

My understanding is that for $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/3},3^{1/4})$ to be a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ there must exist a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with roots $3^{1/3},3^{1/4}$ that splits in $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/3},3^{1/4})$. Is it true then that this field is not a Galois extension in this case as the field does not contain $i$ (since some roots of $x^3-3$ and $x^4-3$ are complex) or am I missing the point?

Thanks.

Comment: The field will always contain $i$.

Comment: Yes. A Galois extension must contain all roots of the minimal polynomial of an element in the field.

Comment: @Bernard So this field is not a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is what you are saying then?

Comment: @FlinnD: Exactly. Of course checking whether this property is true or false for generators of the extension is enough.

Comment: @Bernard Ok thank you.

Comment: It's funny that this question was asked two days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287643/is-mathbbq-sqrt33-sqrt43-a-galois-extension-of-mathbbq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right on the point: some roots of $x^3-3$ are complex.

More precisely:

- A Galois extension contains all the algebraic conjugates of its elements.
- $3^{1/3}$ has algebraic conjugates that are complex, such as $3^{1/3}\omega$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cubic root of unity.
- $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/3},3^{1/4}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/3},3^{1/4})$ does not contain all the algebraic conjugates of $3^{1/3}$ and so is not a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.